# QUOTIENT of numbers returns invalid value

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I am filling one column of a table using

```
=QUOTIENT([RemainingRuntime];25)
```

with `[RemainingRuntime]` being a numerical field that is filled using the `DAYS` function. I did also check that is indeed numeric via `ISNUMBER`.

However my `QUOTIENT` always returns `#VALUE!`. According to the documentation that means that one value is nonnumeric. What could be causing this?

Comment: From [support.office.com](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/quotient-function-9f7bf099-2a18-4282-8fa4-65290cc99dee) Tip: If you want to divide numeric values, you should use the "/" operator as there isn't a DIVIDE function in Excel. For example, to divide 5 by 2, you would type =5/2 into a cell, which returns 2.5. The QUOTIENT function for these same numbers =QUOTIENT(5,2) returns 2, since QUOTIENT doesn't return a remainder. For other ways to divide numbers, see [Divide numbers](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/multiply-and-divide-numbers-4585b0ea-0ea0-4faf-84e4-3db5d4b2dc5d).

Comment: @Jeeped Thanks for the advice, but the `QUOTIENT` function is doing exactly what I am looking for. I want to divide integer values without the remainder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it as,

```
'for EN-US systems
=QUOTIENT([@RemainingRuntime], 25)
'for systems using a semi-colon as a regional list separator
=QUOTIENT([@RemainingRuntime]; 25)
```

Note the warning about QUOTIENT I left in the comments above.